# Why can't add the black line underline characters?

Tags: html, css

I want to add a black line on some characters,the black line was background photo.
Please download the file as line.gif ,and to save the following css code as name `insert_line.html` into same directory with line.gif.

[image]

```css
body{
width:1000px;
margin:0 auto;}


.prod_list_title_bar{ 
width:1000px;
height:40px;
float:left;
line-height:18px;
font-size:15px;
color:#565656;
background: url(../line.gif) no-repeat center; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="prod_list">
    <div class="prod_list_title_bar">books</div>
</div>
</div>
```

What i want is the following.
[image]
What i get with my css code is the following.
[image]
Why my css code can't add the line.gif underline the characters `books`?

Comment: We don't download files..it's your job to create demos that **include** them...and why not just use a border?

Comment: And why are you saying a "black line on some characters" when it appears to just be an underline or bottom border?

Comment: Can I just ask what is so special about your line, that you cannot create it via CSS and at least reduce server calls by 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to add a line to something in CSS, just give it a border:

```
.prod_list_title_bar {
    border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc;
    padding-bottom:5px; /*This is to set the distance from the words*/
    margin-bottom:10px; /*This is to set the distance to the top of the next line*/
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/92L4pctg/1/

Also included in that example is for "add a black line on some characters", which if I'm reading correctly means you want to have the line under just a certain word?

Since you're really asking about putting the pic under your word, here's what's going on.

Your word container is not large enough to see the bottom of your image.  You can either increase your `line-height` to see the bottom of the image, or use `background-position:bottom;`

```
.prod_list_title_bar {
    background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSc6d.gif');
    background-position: bottom;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Updated Fiddle to show this: https://jsfiddle.net/92L4pctg/3/

Comment: I know the method to set `border-bottom:1px solid`,but why my css code can't  put  the line.gif underline `books`?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature, I've updated my code above to accommodate for your image.  The height of your word is probably not tall enough to make its container tall enough to see the bottom of your line.